# How to use the verb "overload" in a passive sentence

Tags: phrasal-verbs, passive-voice

My sentence is "Do not overload the equipment" and I want to change it into "The equipment shouldn't be ..." form. How should the verb "overload" be used in this situation?

Is it "overloaded" or "loaded over"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only

*The equipment should **not** be **overloaded**.*

is valid.

Use the past participle ("overloaded'). If this is formal, do not use contractions.

For instruction on the passive voice and examples, read several of the threads [here](http://goo.gl/ChB6IJ).